# how to resolve my BeansException in spring

Tags: spring

i am new to spring technology.I am trying to create simple spring standalone application using j2ee container.

for that i added 4 jar files.

```
1)commons-loggins-1.3 jar
2)spring_bean_3.0.5
3)spring_core_3.0.0
4)Spring_context_3.0.2
```

i am tring to create application context instance in my client class.i am getting following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The type org.springframework.beans.BeansException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    The constructor ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String) refers to the missing type BeansException

    at test.Core_J2ee_Client.main(Core_J2ee_Client.java:12)
```

This is my code.

this is my client class.

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import beans.Test;

public class Core_J2ee_Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext ap = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resource/spring.xml");

    }

}
```

This is my pojo class.

```
package beans;

public class Test {

    public Test(){
        System.out.println("this is test cons---");
    }
    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("this is hello method");
    }
}
```

This is my spring.xml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"  
        "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
<bean id="t" class="beans.Test">
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Maybe it's a version conflict problem. Use a same version of different spring modules and also use current version of spring framework which is `4.2.4`.

Comment: In order to have a more pleasant java development, use `maven` or `gradle` for dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

Include this dependency in your pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.10</version>
</dependency>
```

And also include this spring configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- bean definitions here -->

</beans>
```